# How to delete a header for a given name in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, http-headers, httpclient

In my app, I'm doing multiple HTTP requests. All of them need an authentication header with an access token (and some other header values). I defined in a header variable of type `HttpHeaders` (see code#1) to use it like `this.http.get(this.myUrl, { headers: this.headers})`.
In my case, the token has to be refreshed over time and I want to change the header to contain the newest token.

In my code, I have a refresh function which should refresh the token and replace the old token in the HTTP header with the new one.
My first approach was to use the provided [set() method](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders#set)(see code#2). This added a new value to the header and did not replace it (I now had two vales of Authorization).
My second approach was to use the [delete() method](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders#delete)(see code#3) and delete Authorization and then use the [append() method](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders#append) and a new one. This caused a similar result.
My last approach was to just use the delete() method(see code#4).

#### code samples

code#1:

```
headers = new HttpHeaders()
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  .set('Accept', 'application/json');
```

code#2:

```
this.headers = this.headers
  .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + access_token);
```

code#3:

```
this.headers = this.headers.delete('Authorization');
this.headers = this.headers.append('Authorization','Bearer ' + access_token);
```

code#4:

```
this.headers = this.headers.delete('Authorization','Bearer ' + access_token);
```

#### results

I expected that either the value of the header `({'Authorization', 'Bearer ' + access_token})` gets replaced (1st approach). The actual result was that it just got appended:

```
{"Authorization", "Bearer access_token-old"}
{"Authorization", "Bearer access_token-new"}
```

And for the second approach, I expected to delete and appending a new value which caused to still adding two values:

```
{"Authorization", undefined}
{"Authorization", "Bearer access_token-new"}
```

My last approach caused the same output as in my first approach, instead of just replacing the value.

Do you know any method to just replace the access_token/value in `{'Authorization','Bearer ' + access_token}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find an easy workaround to fit my case:

1. I'm defining the header:

```
headers = new HttpHeaders()
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  .set('Accept', 'application/json');
```

2. Every time I need to refresh the token I do this:

```
this.headers = new HttpHeaders()
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  .set('Accept', 'application/json')
  .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + access_token');
```

But If anybody has an idea how to do it with set(), append(), delet(), etc. I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');
headers = headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');
headers = headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${access_token}`);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it still just added an identical one (so still two same values).